# Meteor Reference Error

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm slightly new to programming and was hoping if someone could help me figure out the problem with my app. [Here is the link to my Repo in Github](https://github.com/edkim1/myMusicApp).

The Error:

```
W202306-18:14:53.145(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/Ed/appTest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:184
W202306-18:14:53.146(-4)? (STDERR) }).run();
W202306-18:14:53.146(-4)? (STDERR)    ^
W202306-18:14:53.147(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: require is not defined
W202306-18:14:53.148(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/stripe/test/charges.js:1:47
W202306-18:14:53.148(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/stripe/test/charges.js:65:3
W202306-18:14:53.149(-4)? (STDERR)     at mains (/Users/Ed/appTest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:153:10)
W202306-18:14:53.149(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W202306-18:14:53.149(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Ed/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W202306-18:14:53.150(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Ed/appTest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:80:5
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a number of issues mainly related to application folder structure and use of packages in meteor.

1.) **App Structure**: By default for every file in your project meteor will attempt to load it both client and server side. If you want to separate files for client and server you need to use to put them in client and server folders. There are other key folder names that meteor looks out for like packages, lib etc. These are explained in the 'Structuring your app' section of the meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com

The problems you have are that your jQuery plugin and Stripe module are in your project root so when server side code looks at jQuery it doesn't know what to do and when a client looks at all your Stripe module's code which is written like a node.js app it doesn't know how to handle it.

Now you do have a 'Client' folder but as I just found out when looking at your problem, meteor is very picky and so requires it to all be undercase. So first of all rename the Client folder to client. Next move the jquery-jplayer folder inside the client folder. Lastly I would suggest making a server folder and moving your node module into there but instead I'll suggest a better way...

2.) **Using packages with meteor**: With a standard node.js app you would simply do 'npm install module-name'. In meteor packages tend to be handled differently. First of all instead of doing npm install you can request a package server side by doing Npm.require('module-name'); Secondly packages have a standard way of being made which is explained in the 'Writing packages' of the meteor docs. I'll save you all the details and just explain how to get Stripe working in your app.

Luckily somebody else has created a Stripe package for Meteor. As well as the standard packages bundled with meteor like backbone, accounts etc. there is a repository of packages made by community members. To install these packages you need to install a command line tool called meteorite. The details to do so are explained here: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/app . Then to install the Stripe package that was made by Tyler Johnson (https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/stripe) simply do 'mrt add stripe' from your project's root directory. Next delete the node_modules folder you currently have. From now on to run your meteor app type 'mrt' in command line instead of 'meteor', this is required because you are now use meteorite packages in this app, for future apps that don't make use of meteorite packages you can continue simply using 'meteor'

**Other minor errors:**

- on line 11 myMusicApp.html you reference template name {{> Playlist}} instead of Playlists
- on line 32 myMusicApp.js you invoke the jPlayer by $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jplayer({...
  but you have to use a capital P i.e. $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer (you will find out in programming that stuff is very specific when it comes to capital letters or lack of)
- the last errors come from your events in myMusicApp.js, specifically the okCancelEvents stuff. I'm not sure what you are trying to do in that bit, the mousedown, click and dblclick events above it look fine.

Comment: This doesn't address ReferenceError

Answer (score -1):

[ReferenceError](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_referenceerror) is a Node error.  Meteor is a framework on top of Node.

Node has a global scope (aka Node's `global` variable).  **This error is thrown by Node (not Meteor) if you try to access an undefined global variable.**

Browsers also have a global scope called `window`, and do not throw ReferenceErrors when undefined variables are accessed.

Here's a pattern I like for adding functionality to a class (it's very Meteor):

```
/lib/Helpers.js      <-- Helpers for everyone (node+browser)
/server/Helpers.js   <-- Server helpers (node)
/client/Helpers.js   <-- Client helpers (browser)
```

Consider these implementations:

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
Helpers = {/* functions */};  // Assigned to window.Helpers and global.Helpers

// /server/Helpers.js
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/*more functions*/}

// /client/Helpers.js
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/*more functions*/}
```

This is a trivial example.  What if I didn't want to worry about load order?  Why not _.extend() in /lib/Helpers.js?

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
// Helpers = {/* functions */};                  // Overwrites...
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/* functions */});  // ReferenceError
```

Because you'll get a ReferenceError from Node if Helpers isn't defined - specifically the "Helpers" used as an argument.  (Node knows to assign Helpers as global.Helpers).

**Here are two ways to "fix" this:**

1) Assign Helpers to something

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
// Helpers = Helpers || {};   // Also a ReferenceError
if (typeof Helpers === 'undefined') Helpers = {};
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/* functions */});
```

2) Use helpers from the global

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
Helpers = _.extend(global.Helpers, {/* functions */});  // works in node, but...
```

**Both of which suck.**

1)'s syntax is horrible.  But fine for first declarations I guess.
  2) works in node, but there is no global in browsers.  So it fails it's purpose.

If you have a handy cross-platform syntax for this, do comment :-)

Comment: Please don't post identical answers. Flag questions as duplicates if necessary, or tailor your answer to the individual question.

Comment: @miken - Nice!  You buried the correct answer to a question that comes up as a top search result!  Who are you helping?  Now I remember why I don't waste time answering questions here.

Comment: Actually it's a poor-quality question that's only been viewed 1000 times in the 3.5 years since it was asked. The asker made no attempt to debug the problem, or even provide their code. IMO these are not the sort of questions that need answering; if others feel differently they will upvote your answer, and ignore my VTC on the question. (And none of this changes the fact that posting identical answers is frowned upon, and will automatically raise moderation flags.)